# Send SMS via GSM modem mvc4 c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, sms

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC 4 web application where I need to send SMS to multiple users. At the moment I use Clickatell for this, but it is expensive in my context, and I am searching for a way to do this using a GSM modem.
If there is a library or a way I can use AT commands in C#, please let me know.

Comment: You need something that acts as a GSM modem, this is unrelated to internet connectivity. You would of course still accrue operator charges.

Comment: Yes, I 'll update the question and remove the internet reference. The operator chargers in our country are around 20 times less than clickatell charges.

Comment: GSMComm http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm